# Swift 3: How to add or remove parameters in Request Body in ALamofire 4?

Tags: ios, swift, parameters, httprequest, alamofire

I am using **Alamofire** library for REST API calls. I have a Request Body of type
**Dictionary(String, Any)**. There are few objects in the Request Body that are common for some APIs.

For eg:  1st API call contains following parameters in the request body.

```
var hotel = HotelParameter()
var food = foodParameter()
var address = addressParameter()

class RequestParameters: NSObject{

func parameter() -> NSDictionary {

   var parameter : [String : Any] = [:]
   parameter["hotels"] = hotel.params()
   parameter["foodType"] = food.params()
   parameter["address"] = address.params()

   return parameter as! NSDictionary
}
```

Now in 2nd API call I have to pass only "**hotels**" and "**address**" in the RequestParameter. 
My problem is: **How to add or remove any extra parameter in the Alamofire Request Body?**

Since I cannot add Request Body for 'n' number of Requests, there has to be a single RequestParameter which will get modified according to the api calls. There can be extra or single Parameter(s) in the Body. 
Mostly "**hotels**" will be a common parameter for all Request Body.

I have tried a lot to solve this, But I get exception because it cannot parse some JSON response.
I have created functions to hit the api calls and I am passing the parameters like this.

```
var requestParam = RequestParamters()

Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: requestParam.parameter(),
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (data : DataResponse<Any>) in
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use NSDictionary in Swift 3+, but more Dictionary (Swift versions). Maybe you want to do also `requestParam.parameters(withKeys:["hotel", "address"])` that would return the param only with theses keys and the corressponding values, or if you API calls have "names", `requestParam.parameters(name:"APICallName1")` etc.

Comment: where is `requestParam.parameters(withKeys:["hotel", "address"])`.. Sorry did not get you

Comment: Create an additional method that returns you the dictionary with the wanted key/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out Two ways to do it.

1. Create an addExtraParams :[String : Any] =  :   type of Dictionary and add the `key : value` pair you need in this.
2. Create Requests functions for respective apis and just update the value of the required parameters using the `object` you get after logging.

For eg:

```
var user = response.object as! Person
var request = RequestParameters()
request.hotel.name = user.hotel_name
```

Update the values before the Alamofire request in the function that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I got your requirement right. But as per my understanding, you have to hit one API multiple times, and the parameter shall be different every time. So just write a method which'll take parameter as a method argument. Here is the sample code as per your requirement.

```
func getAllHotels(_ params:Dictionary, callback:@escaping (Dictionary<String, Any>, Error?)->Void)
{
     let parameters: Parameters = params

    Alamofire.request(baseUrl + "/getHotels", method: .post,parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON    { response in
        debugPrint("All Response from API: \(response)")
        switch response.result
        {
        case .success(let value):
            callback(value as! Dictionary, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            callback([:], error)
        }
    }
}

/** Now call the above method with your required parameters **/
```